# overriding Django change_list_results

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

[image]

I am customizing my admin panel a little and want to add an additional column to it, so as per the docs I have to override the change_form_results.html file but how do I do it? all I see is this code in it

```
<tbody>
{% for result in results %}
{% if result.form and result.form.non_field_errors %}
  
    <tr><td colspan="{{ result|length }}">{{ result.form.non_field_errors }}</td> </tr>
{% endif %}
<tr>{% for item in result %}
  
  {{ item }}
   
  {% endfor %}</tr>
{% endfor %}

</tbody>
```

what change am i suppose to make to above code

Comment: To add an additional column you do not need to change the template, this can be done from the ModelAdmin. What do you want this additional column to contain?

Comment: I don't want a column for data, i want it to display a button on each row , on whose click some further action can be done @IainShelvington

Comment: What do you want this button to do? The additional columns added via ModelAdmin can contain whatever you want

Comment: I want to add an instance using that button click by displaying a modal(bootstrap one) like change form does any snippet or references

Comment: So you just want to display a button on every row and you already have some JS to display a modal when it's clicked?

Comment: yea, libraries can be included but I need a button with the proper route for that @IainShelvington